# NMaximize not solving my problem

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Check the following, integer problem:

```
NMaximize[{3*0.5*(80 - P)*Subscript[Q, 1]*z1 + 
   2*0.5*(125 - P)*Subscript[Q, 2]*z2 + 
   1*0.5*(180 - 2*P)*Subscript[Q, 3]*z3,
  Subscript[Q, 1] == (80 - P) y1, 
  Subscript[Q, 2] == (100 - 0.8 P) y2, 
  Subscript[Q, 3] == (90 - 0.5 P) y3, 20 <= P <= 90, 1 >= y1 >= 0, 
  1 >= y2 >= 0, 1 >= y3 >= 0, 3 >= y1 + y2 + y3 >= 2, 1 >= z1 >= 0, 
  1 >= z2 >= 0, 1 >= z3 >= 0, z1 + z2 + z3 == 1, 
  3 <= y1 + y2 + y3 + z1 + z2 + z3 <= 4, y1 + y2 + y3 + z2 <= 3, 
  y1 + y2 + y3 + z3 <= 3, Subscript[Q, 1] >= 0, Subscript[Q, 2] >= 10,
   Subscript[Q, 3] >= 10, {y1, y2, y3, z1, z2, z3} \[Element] 
   Integers}, {P, Subscript[Q, 2], Subscript[Q, 3], Subscript[Q, 1], 
  y1, y2, y3, z1, z2, z3}]
```

Mathematica fails to find the optimal solution, which is

> `P->20, Q2->84, Q3->80, Y2->1, Y3->1, Z2->1`

LINGO finds the global optimal solution automatically. I have tried with all methods provided in tutorial, but it did not help, unless I increased the lower bound to about `Q2 > 60` and `Q3 >60`.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that if I did not use Q1, Q2, or Q3 as intermediate values in the maximization then it worked:

```
NMaximize[{
  3*0.5*(80-P)*(80-P)*y1*z1 + 2*0.5*(125-P)*(100-0.8P)*y2*z2 + 1*0.5*(180-2P)*(90 - 0.5)*y3*z3,
  20 <= P <= 90,
  0 <= y1 <= 1,
  0 <= y2 <= 1,
  0 <= y3 <= 1,
  2 <= y1 + y2 + y3 <= 3,
  0 <= z1 <= 1,
  0 <= z2 <= 1,
  0 <= z3 <= 1,
  z1 + z2 + z3 == 1,
  3 <= y1 + y2 + y3 + z1 + z2 + z3 <= 4,
  y1 + y2 + y3 + z2 <= 3,
  y1 + y2 + y3 + z3 <= 3,
  (80 - P) y1 >= 0,
  (100 - 0.8 P) y2 >= 10,
  (90 - 0.5 P) y3 >= 10,
  {y1, y2, y3, z1, z2, z3} \[Element] Integers},
  {P, y1, y2, y3, z1, z2, z3}
]
```

This gave me the value:

```
{8820., {P->20, y1->0, y2->1, y3->1, z1->0, z2->1, z3->0}}
```

It appears that the constraints should only contain independent variables, and no dependent variables.

Comment: Michael, thanks very much for that. It helps a lot, but still the problem was not to find out the integer values, but the Q-values. I formulated it so that the integer (binary) will force to obtain the correct Q-values. I am surprised though that LINGO finds both the independent and dependent variables in a millisecond!

Comment: @ACMilan `max=NMaximize[...];{P, y1, y2, y3, z1, z2, z3} = {P, y1, y2, y3, z1, z2, z3} /. Last@max;Q1 = (80 - P) y1
Q2 = (100 - 0.8 P) y2
Q3 = (90 - 0.5 P) y3` gives exactly  the LINGO's solution.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using subscripts!

```
NMaximize[{3*0.5*(80 - P)*Q1*z1 + 2*0.5*(125 -P)*Q2*z2 + 
1*0.5*(180 - 2*P)*Q3*z3, Q1 == (80 - P) y1, Q2 == 
(100 - 0.8 P) y2,
Q3 == (90 - 0.5 P) y3, 20 <= P <= 90, 1 >= y1 >= 0, 1 
>= y2 >= 0, 
1 >= y3 >= 0, 3 >= y1 + y2 + y3 >= 2, 1 >= z1 >= 0, 1 
>= z2 >= 0, 
1 >= z3 >= 0, z1 + z2 + z3 == 1, 
3  <= y1 + y2 + y3 + z1 + z2 + z3 <= 4, y1 + y2 + y3 
+ z2 <= 3, 
y1 + y2 + y3 + z3 <= 3, Q1 >= 0, Q2 >= 10, 
Q3 >= 10, {y1, y2, y3, z1, z2, z3} \[Element] 
Integers}, {P, Q2, Q3,
Q1, y1, y2, y3, z1, z2, z3}] 

(*{0.0741345, {P -> 79.7791, Q2 -> 10., Q3 -> 10., Q1-> 0.22375,y1 -> 1, y2 -> 0, y3 -> 0, z1 -> 1, z2 -> 0, z3 ->0}}*)
```

Comment: Ulrich,Subscripts make no difference; that is not the optimal solution! It is exactly the one NMaximize gives, which is wrong.

Comment: @ACMilan Obviously we get a different solution without subscripts...

Answer (score 1):

Since Binary domain is small we can use this approach.

```
pts = Select[
  Tuples[{0, 1}, 
   6], ((2 <= #[[1]] + #[[2]] + #[[3]] <= 
       3) && (#[[4]] + #[[5]] + #[[6]] == 1) && (3 <= Total@# <= 
       4) && (#[[1]] + #[[2]] + #[[3]] + #[[5]] <= 
       3) && (#[[1]] + #[[2]] + #[[3]] + #[[6]] <= 3)) &]
```

This gives All tuples with the constrains.

> {y1, y2, y3, z1, z2, z3}={{0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1,
>   0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
>   1}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}}

Now we Maximize the obj func for each set of `{y1, y2, y3, z1, z2, z3}`

```
Table[ClearAll[y1, y2, y3, z1, z2, z3];
  {y1, y2, y3, z1, z2, z3} = pts[[i]];
  NMaximize[{3/2*(80 - P)*Q1*z1 + (125 - P)*Q2*z2 + 
     1/2*(180 - 2*P)*Q3*z3, Q1 == (80 - P) y1, Q2 == (100 - 4/5 P) y2,
     Q3 == (90 - 1/2 P) y3, 20 <= P <= 90, Q1 >= 0, Q2 >= 10, 
    Q3 >= 10}, {P, Q1, Q2, Q3}], {i, Length@pts}] // Quiet
```

> {{5600., {P -> 20., Q1 -> 0, Q2 -> 84.,     Q3 -> 80.}}, {8820., {P ->
>   20., Q1 -> 0, Q2 -> 84.,     Q3 -> 80.}}, {0., {P -> 20.092, Q1 -> 0, Q2 -> 83.9264,     Q3 -> 79.954}}, {-[Infinity], {P -> Indeterminate,
>   Q1 -> Indeterminate, Q2 -> Indeterminate,     Q3 -> Indeterminate}},
>   {-[Infinity], {P -> Indeterminate,     Q1 -> Indeterminate, Q2 ->
>   Indeterminate,     Q3 -> Indeterminate}}, {-[Infinity], {P ->
>   Indeterminate,     Q1 -> Indeterminate, Q2 -> Indeterminate,     Q3 ->
>   Indeterminate}}, {-[Infinity], {P -> Indeterminate,     Q1 ->
>   Indeterminate, Q2 -> Indeterminate,     Q3 -> Indeterminate}},
>   {-[Infinity], {P -> Indeterminate,     Q1 -> Indeterminate, Q2 ->
>   Indeterminate,     Q3 -> Indeterminate}}, {-[Infinity], {P ->
>   Indeterminate,     Q1 -> Indeterminate, Q2 -> Indeterminate,     Q3 ->
>   Indeterminate}}, {5400., {P -> 20., Q1 -> 60., Q2 -> 84.,     Q3 ->
>   80.}}}

It is clear that Max value is `8820` with the values `{P -> 20., Q1 -> 0, Q2 -> 84., Q3 -> 80.}` which is second solution. So `{y1, y2, y3, z1, z2, z3} ={0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0}`

Comment: Good approach (+1). I am not sure, though, is the OP question about (i) finding a solution with Mathematica or (ii) explaining or tweaking the behavior of `NMaximize` in order to find a solution.

Comment: Hi Anton. Exactly, my question was why NMaximize fails for such a small problem. I love Mathematica by the way!